# how to grep required till some condition while file processing in perl scripts

Tags: regex, linux, perl, file

I want to capture and make one line for the following varieties of warnings

here's the code snippet which i am using for gathering different warnings and after observing warnings pattern i have warnings of different lines and i want join next line warning part in one line and assign to it a hash ref.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(FH,"/home/goudar/Desktop/1.log") or die !$;

while(<FH>){
    my $line = $_;
    if($line =~ m/^Warning: (.*)$/){
                my $date1 = `date`;
                chomp($date1);
                $subStepValues = {
                    Warning => $1,
                    Warning_timeStamp => $date1,
                };
                push @{$subsSteps->{'subStepValues'}}, $subStepValues;
            }
}
close(FH);
```

**FILE**

```
Warning: No clock-gating check is inferred for clock clk_12800 
at pins i_osc/i_osc_top/i_clk_div/g817/S and i_osc/i_osc_top/i_clk_div/g817/A1 of cell i_osc/i_osc_top/i_clk_div/g817. (PTE-060)
Warning: Virtual clock 'clk_vir' cannot be made propagated. (UITE-316)
Warning: Virtual clock 'clk_ext' cannot be made propagated. (UITE-316)
Warning: Net i_obr/i_obr34/rec2 has been annotated with max resistance
using the set_resistance command.  This takes precedence over
values from parasitics. (PARA-047)
Warning: Net i_obr/i_obr34/rec2 has been annotated with min resistance
using the set_resistance command.  This takes precedence over
values from parasitics. (PARA-047)
```

Comment: @zdim i have modified the script for my post here. can you help me to find the solution for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need very small additions to your code.

The only possibility other than matching `/^Warning:/` is the continuation of it on the next line(s), which is exactly what you want.  So you can add an `else` branch and in it append the line to the last previously matched '*Warning*'. This handles multiple such lines as well, they all get appended to the last '*Warning*', one after another.
So you need to:

1) Remember the position in the array of the last match ('*Warning*')

2) Add an `else` in which you append the line to that last '*Warning*', using the last value of the counter. 

 For this to work you now have to `chomp` the line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FH,"/home/goudar/Desktop/1.log") or die !$;

my $subStepValues;   # added missing declarations
my $subsSteps = { };

my $cnt = -1;                                   # added
while (<FH>) {
    chomp(my $line = $_);                       # added
    if ($line =~ m/^Warning: (.*)$/) {
        $cnt++;                                 # added
        my $date1 = `date`;
        chomp($date1);
        $subStepValues = { 
            Warning => $1, 
            Warning_timeStamp => $date1,
        };
        push @{ $subsSteps->{'subStepValues'} }, $subStepValues;
    }   
    else {                                      # added
        $subsSteps->{'subStepValues'}->[$cnt]->{'Warning'} .= " $line";
    }   
}
close(FH);

foreach my $ss (@{$subsSteps->{'subStepValues'}}) { # added, print
    foreach my $key (keys %{$ss}) {
        print "$key => $ss->{$key}\n";
    }   
}
```

This prints all lines belonging to each '*Warning*'.

I recommend three-argument open, `open my $fh, '<', $infile`, and then `while ($fh) { }`.

---

Alternatively, you can read the whole file into one string (or read it into an array and join) and remove new lines. Then split that string on `Warning:` (drop the first element, an empty string), or match the same way as you do, but globally (`/g` modifier).

This forms an array where each element is a string with all text belonging to its`/^Warning:/`. Then make another pass over that array, to add that time stamp and put it all into your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that what you really want, is to split your record on something other than linefeed. Then you can use multi-line pattern matches to extract your content.

Looking at it - the 'end of record' appears to be `)`.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @warnings;

open my $input, '<', '/home/goudar/Desktop/1.log' or die $!;

local $/ = ')';
while (<$input>) {
    my $timestamp      = time();
    my $formatted_time = localtime(); 
    my ($code)         = m/\(([\w\d\-]+)\)/;
    my ($message)      = m/Warning: (.*)\z/ms;
    next unless $code;
    push( @warnings, { time => $timestamp, formatted_time => $formatted_time, 
                       msg  => $message,   code           => $code } );
}
close ( $input ); 


print Dumper \@warnings;
```

This gives (with your content):

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'msg' => 'No clock-gating check is inferred for clock clk_12800 
at pins i_osc/i_osc_top/i_clk_div/g817/S and i_osc/i_osc_top/i_clk_div/g817/A1 of cell i_osc/i_osc_top/i_clk_div/g817. (PTE-060)',
            'time' => 1457430459,
            'code' => 'PTE-060',
            'formatted_time' => 'Tue Mar  8 09:47:39 2016'
          },
          {
            'formatted_time' => 'Tue Mar  8 09:47:39 2016',
            'msg' => 'Virtual clock \'clk_vir\' cannot be made propagated. (UITE-316)',
            'time' => 1457430459,
            'code' => 'UITE-316'
          },
          {
            'formatted_time' => 'Tue Mar  8 09:47:39 2016',
            'code' => 'UITE-316',
            'msg' => 'Virtual clock \'clk_ext\' cannot be made propagated. (UITE-316)',
            'time' => 1457430459
          },
          {
            'formatted_time' => 'Tue Mar  8 09:47:39 2016',
            'msg' => 'Net i_obr/i_obr34/rec2 has been annotated with max resistance
using the set_resistance command.  This takes precedence over
values from parasitics. (PARA-047)',
            'time' => 1457430459,
            'code' => 'PARA-047'
          },
          {
            'msg' => 'Net i_obr/i_obr34/rec2 has been annotated with min resistance
using the set_resistance command.  This takes precedence over
values from parasitics. (PARA-047)',
            'time' => 1457430459,
            'code' => 'PARA-047',
            'formatted_time' => 'Tue Mar  8 09:47:39 2016'
          }
        ];
```

Whilst we're at it:

- 3 argument `open` with lexical filehandles is much better style.
- `my $line = $_` is redundant. You can do `while ( my $line = <$filehandle> ) {`
- you don't need it if all you're doing is regex anyway, because the default match target is `$_`
- unclear what you're doing with `$substeps` so I've used an array in the above for clarity.
- It's usually a good idea to keep an unformatted time, because that enables sorting/searching etc.
- the above captures linefeeds in your messages. This can be easily remedied by `$message =~ tr/\n//d;`